# How to post raw XML in a functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a REST service that handles an XML via POST:

```
class DepartmentsController < ApplicationController

  # POST /departments/1/employees.xml
  def create
    params[:employees].each do |e| # <employees type="array">
      @employee = Employee.new(e)
      @employee.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.any { head status }
    end
  end

end
```

The XML it expects is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exmployees type="array">
  <employee>
    ...
  </employe>
  <employee>
    ...
  </employe>
</employees>
```

The service works as expected when interacting with an iPhone app, but I can't manage to get it working with my functional test (I'm a Rails newbie).

So here's what I'm trying:

```
  test "should create employees with client data" do
    xml_out = ""

    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => xml_out, :indent => 2)
    xml.instruct!
    xml.employees :type => "array" do
      xml.employee do
        # ...
      end
    end

    assert_difference('Employee.count') do
      @request.env['RAW_POST_BODY'] = xml_out
      post :create, :department_id => 234
    end
  end
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
```

It seems the 'params' variable is missing the post data:

```
{"department_id"=>234, "controller"=>"employees", "action"=>"create"}
```

I've checked the content of 'xml_out', and it does contain the properly formed XML. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
post :create, :department_id => 234, :employees => Hash.from_xml(xml_out)
```

**EDIT**

From the comments, the final solution was:

```
post :create, :department_id => 234, :employees => Hash.from_xml(xml_out)["employees"]
```

Comment: If I do this, the raw XML is just passed as parameter (with no automatic hashing). In this case, I'd need to do it myself in the controller.

Comment: just edited my answer, to use Hash.from_xml. I think rails automagicaly do this for you when a request comes with a parameter that have xml in it.

Comment: I thought it worked, but actually hashing the XML this way and sending it as 'employees' param leads to {"employees"=>{"employees"=>[{"... on the action controller side, while I'm expecting just {"employees"=>[{"...

Comment: oh, try post :create, :department_id => 234, Hash.from_xml(xml_out)

Comment: or post :create, :department_id => 234, :employees => Hash.from_xml(xml_out)["employees"]

Comment: The last one finally did the trick. You've saved the day, thanks again :)